# Oracle access Manager password validator API Payload issue

Tags: rest, oid, oim, oracle-access-manager

I would like to use Standard **oracle access manager password validator API** in my mobile Application for login validation.
We have tried many ways but the API is getting 404 not found error or 400 Bad request error.
We don't know what is the exact payload we have to use for this.

The below is the API we are trying for Password validation.

**URL : https://baseurl/oam/services/rest/access/api/v1/pswdmanagement/PasswordValidateRequests/${userid}**
**Doc reference** :  https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/access-manager/12.2.1.3/orpdm/op-passwordvalidaterequests-userid-post.html

Below is the sample payload which we are trying

```
{
"ValidatePasswordRequest": [
{
"username": "Vu88790",
"password": "O123#ASDFzmns@2023"
}
]
}
```

Kindly anyone help me on this.

Thanks,
Janani